# How to customize a folder in c# without creating ini file within that folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, directory

I was trying to customize a folder. Mainly to control the folder icon. This was achieved when desktop.ini file was created within that folder with my custom settings. Now I would want to customize the folder without doing any change(add/ remove) in that folder. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe show us some code?  Then we might be able to help you figure out what isn't working.

Comment: in C# it's not possible you must have to update the desktop.ini file

Comment: @roryap  The code is similar to the first answer. That works well. But as I am not supposed to do any modifications within the folder, I am thinking of other way to get it done.

Comment: @DhavalPatel Ok! If not it c#, What else could help me achieve this?

Comment: @dp94:c++ or vc++ may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this could be done without inifile. It just that we have to implement a Shell Icon Overlay Handler, a COM object which implements the **IShellIconOverlayIdentifier** interface. This document helped a lot. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects

Comment: Are you sure that you can change the folder icon? It seems that, with this method, you can change the small icons on files and not the icon of a folder.

Comment: I am pretty sure that writing a Shell Icon Overlay Handler would change the folder icon.

Comment: Probably if you drawing a big icon you can overlay the folder icon, true :-) But, what's the motivation to not change desktop.ini file?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no way to do this but you can do this to hide desktop.ini file even if displays hidden files.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(iniFile);

sw.WriteLine("[.ShellClassInfo]");
sw.WriteLine("IconResource=.\\" + iconPath + ",0");

sw.Close();

File.SetAttributes(filePath, File.GetAttributes(filePath) | FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System);
File.SetAttributes(folderPath, File.GetAttributes(folderPath) | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

I don't remember if last line is necessary because I wrote this code more than one year ago.

Comment: I did the same. Thank you. But even if it is hidden, there is some modification done on the folder (adding an ini file) which shouldn't be done. **Is there any way to control the settings of the folder from somewhere else(outside) than from the same folder?**

Comment: I think is not possible because also Windows create desktop.ini file when you change folder icon.

Comment: Actually this could be done without inifile. It just that we have to implement a **Shell Icon Overlay Handler**, a COM object which implements the IShellIconOverlayIdentifier interface. This document helped a lot. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects [reference document](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects)